# Are spider webs flammable?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

In Pathfinder, the Web *spell* explicitly has this to say about flammability:

> ...
>   The strands of a web spell are flammable. A flaming weapon can slash them away as easily as a hand brushes away cobwebs. Any fire can set the webs alight and burn away one 5-foot square in 1 round. All creatures within flaming webs take 2d4 points of fire damage from the flames.
>   ...

The Web (Ex) ability, on the other hand does not say anything about fire at all:

> **Web (Ex)** Creatures with the web ability can use webs to support themselves and up to one additional creature of the same size. In addition, such creatures can throw a web up to eight times per day. This is similar to an attack with a net but has a maximum range of 50 feet, with a range increment of 10 feet, and is effective against targets up to one size category larger than the web spinner. An entangled creature can escape with a successful Escape Artist check or burst the web with a Strength check. Both are standard actions with a DC equal to 10 + 1/2 the creature's HD + the creature's Con modifier. Attempts to burst a web by those caught in it take a –4 penalty.
>
> Web spinners can create sheets of sticky webbing up to three times their size. They usually position these sheets to snare flying creatures but can also try to trap prey on the ground. Approaching creatures must succeed on a DC 20 Perception check to notice a web; otherwise they stumble into it and become trapped as though by a successful web attack. Attempts to escape or burst the webbing gain a +5 bonus if the trapped creature has something to walk on or grab while pulling free. Each 5-foot-square section of web has a number of hit points equal to the Hit Dice of the creature that created it and DR 5/—. A creature can move across its own web at its climb speed and can pinpoint the location of any creature touching its web.

Can you burn through a conventional spider web if trapped in it, instead of the Escape Artist/Strength check?

Answer (score 4):

The wording in the description you posted is pretty explicit that only the web used as a trap (the second use) can be damaged by attacking it. In that case, it has DR 5/- and fire would indeed be an excellent way to damage the web, since fire damage bypasses DR.

The first use as a ranged attack that is "similar to an attack with a net" makes no mention of HP or attacking the web, and has a list of the ways to get out of the web: Escape Artist or Strength Check.

The trap even defines being trapped as "as though by a successful web attack" and then talks about exceptions to those rules, including the HP of the web.

TL;DR: Web as a trap: can be damaged by fire. Web as attack: can not.

Comment: Full disclosure: @TREE is my GM and this question came as a result of our recent session. A Fire Elemental got "attacked" by a Web from a Giant Spider and had difficulty getting out....

But even if "web as attack" and "web as trap" are interpreted as different things, fire is treated as especially effective with the spell, clearing a whole 5 foot square regardless of damage. Part of the question is "Are natural webs tougher?"

Comment: It is very possible to escape from a net, it just takes a full round attack.  http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2jm91?Escaping-from-a-NET. From the paizo official site under weapons: Net  "An entangled creature can escape with a successful DC 20 Escape Artist check (a full-round action). The net has 5 hit points and can be burst with a successful DC 25 Strength check (also a full-round action). A net is useful only against creatures within one size category of you."

Comment: @Josh Some of those details *may* be worth adding to your question, if you specifically want answerers to address those concerns.